# Django ORM fastest query to join two models and get a list of paired tuples

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Here is how my `models.py` look like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

 class Hat(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('foo', 'bar')
```

Now in my `views.py` I want to have a function like:

```
def index(request):
    foo = request.foo
    bars = Bar.objects.all()
    hats = Hat.objects.filter(foo=foo).all()

    #return  ???
```

what I want as output of index function is a list of tuple like `[(bar_1, hat_1),(bar_2, hat_2), ...]` where for each `hat_i` we have `hat_i.bar == bar_i` and if there is no Hat object associated with a `bar_i` I want it to be paired with None.

What's the fastest way that I can build such list in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
foo = request.foo   
bars = Bar.objects.all()
hats = Hat.objects.filter(foo=foo).all()

# List which has bar and hat pairings
final_list = [(x.bar, x) for x in hats]

# if want pairing with None, then do this 
all_bars = set(bars)
included_bars = set([x.bar for x in hats])

no_hat_bars = all_bars - included_bars

for bar in no_hat_bars:
    final_list.append(bar, None)
```

finally, final_list should have required contents.

Comment: I'm mostly looking for a db query which generates the final list, and don't want to do the same logic in memory.

Comment: here we are hitting db only twice, which we would hit anyway. line 2 & 3. there would be more db calls to say the least. right ? or what am I missing ?